# NSDateFormatter: dateFromString returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have the date in the following format:

```
    NSString *dateString = @"1996-08-09T07:00:00Z";
```

I need to extract only the year from the date above:

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    [dateFormat setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];
    [dateFormat setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehaviorDefault];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateString];
    NSLog(@"date : %@", date);
```

Log:

```
    2016-02-15 06:36:47.496 App[46714:5560483] date : (null)
```

I even tried:

```
    [dateFormat setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]
```

but no avail.

[image]

Comment: `dateFormat` set to `NSDateFormatter` clearly doesn't match the format of `dateString`

Comment: this may help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300032/nsdateformatter-datefromstring-always-returns-nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set date format as

```
                            1996-08-09T07:00:00Z
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
```

**update**

```
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
[dateFormat setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
[dateFormat setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehaviorDefault];
NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:@"1996-08-09T07:00:00Z"];
NSLog(@"date : %@", date);
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy"];
NSString *finalStr = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"finalStr : %@", finalStr);
```

output

[image]

Comment: check the updated answer

Comment: downvoters can explain whats wrong here

Comment: not sure who gave downvoted you - sorry.  But i upvoted you so you dont get a hit.

Comment: @user1107173 -- its ok bro , in my answer is hopeful or not

Comment: @trojanfoe - not like that, we know about u , you are good in always

Comment: There is no reason to set the formatter's timezone to the system timezone. Let it default to the user's current timezone. Especially in a case like this where the timezone will be parsed from the date string. There is also no reason to set the formatter's locale to the current locale since that is also the default.

Answer (score 0):

The format:

```
yyyy
```

does not match the date string:

```
1996-08-09T07:00:00Z
```

hence `[NSDateFormatter dateFromString:]` returned `nil`.

You want this format:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ
```

(Note the `X` specifier is [documented](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) as being the correct specifier for `Z` (Zulu Time) however during a discussion with @rmaddy, he has convinced me that `Z` is the correct one to use.)

and then to extract the year using `NSDateComponents`.

Comment: not sure who gave downvoted you - sorry.  But i upvoted you so you dont get a hit.

Comment: Do not quote the `Z` in the date format. The `Z` in the date string represents the string's timezone. If you quote the `Z` in the date format, the formatter will ignore the `Z` and interpret the date string as local time instead of UTC time.

Comment: @rmaddy The unquoted `Z` specifier is not [documented](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) to deal with an input character of `Z` (meaning *zulu time*).  It supports -0800, GMT-8:00, -08:00
or -07:52:58 depending on how many `Z`s you specify. It looks like `X` does, however.

Comment: I just ran a test to be 100% (I was only 99.5% sure before) and I am correct. The `Z` format specifier proper handles the `Z` timezone code as UTC time.

Comment: @rmaddy I am happy to accept that, however it's a bit annoying the documentation appears to be incorrect (or Apple's implementation). Anyway thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
 +(NSDate *)convertUTCDateLocal:(NSString*)inputString
{
    NSString *dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszz";
    //for input
    NSTimeZone *inputTimeZone =[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
    NSDateFormatter *inputDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [inputDateFormatter setTimeZone:inputTimeZone];

    //NSString *inputString = @"2015-07-31T14:00:00+0000";
    [inputDateFormatter setDateFormat:dateFormat];
    NSDate *date = [inputDateFormatter dateFromString:inputString];

    //for output
    NSDateFormatter *outputDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [outputDateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    [outputDateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    [outputDateFormatter setDateFormat: @"yyyy"];

    NSString *outputString = [outputDateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

    NSDate *outputDate = [outputDateFormatter dateFromString:outputString];

    return outputDate;
}
```

Comment: does not provide the year.

Comment: so you want only year from the input?