# Converting a string to NSDate in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am having an issue converting a string to an NSDate in Swift. My date string is in the following format:

```
2016-05-06T14:07:23.430Z
```

I have a function to return a formatted date string as follows and the date string passed into the function is in the format shown above:

```
private func formatDate(theDate:String?) -> String {
    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yy H:mm"
    let actualDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString(theDate!) //always produces nil
    let formattedDate = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(actualDate!)
    return formattedDate
}
```

When trying to get a date object from the string passed into the function, the date object is always nil. Can anyone assist with this issue? Thanks!

Comment: The date format you used (MM-dd-yy H:mm) doesn't match at all the date format of your string (2016-05-06T14:07:23.430Z). Have you read related question ? The `dateFormat` of the `NSDateFormatter` object need to match the string.

Comment: `dateFormatter.dateFormat` does not match the actual format of `2016-05-06T14:07:23.430Z`. You can google or search other stack overflow answers to find the available formatting options to match what you need. There is also a link in @Lion's answer (commented in code) that will point to a list of format options.

Comment: There is a critical error in this method, you got a parameter theDate optional but where you use it in the method you use it with "!". It's wrong! Check it with a guard for example at the start of the method!

Comment: @Pheepster See my Answer working for You,

Comment: @Pheepster: No. The current scheme is "NSString (format 1) => NSDate => NSString (format 2)". So the [NSString (format1) + NSDateFormatter (with format1)] => NSDate => NSDateFormatter (with format2) => NSString (format2).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSDateFormatter dateFromString Always Returns nil](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300032/nsdateformatter-datefromstring-always-returns-nil)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**See this answer :**

```
let myDateString = "2016-05-06T14:07:23.430Z"

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-dd-MM'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z"
let dateFromString = dateFormatter.dateFromString(myDateString)

let dateFormatter1  = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter1.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yy H:mm"
let getDate =  dateFormatter1.stringFromDate(dateFromString!)

print(getDate)
```

**Your OUTPUT :**

[image]

Comment: @JulienQuere Update my answer

Answer (score 2):

```
let strDate = "2016-05-06T14:07:23.430Z"

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(strDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

You used a bad DateFormat. You should not use the same `NSDateFormatter` for you input date and for your output date.

Try this: `yyyy-dd-MM'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'` for your input. Here is a fully working solution:

```
func formatDate(theDate: String?) -> String {

    let inputDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    inputDateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-dd-MM'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
    let outputDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    outputDateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yy H:mm"

    let actualDate = inputDateFormatter.dateFromString(theDate!)
    let formattedDate = outputDateFormatter.stringFromDate(actualDate!)
    return formattedDate
}

formatDate("2016-05-06T14:07:23.430Z") // returns 06-05-16 14:07
```