# dateFromString returning nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I have a function to convert NSString to NSDate.

```
+ (NSDate *)getNSDateFromString:(NSString *)strDate andFormat:(NSString *)format{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat : format];
    NSString *stringTime = strDate;
    NSDate *dateTime = [formatter dateFromString:stringTime];
    return dateTime;
}
```

The value of strDate is "27-Mar-2018 18:28:09".
The format is "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"

That function is returning nil value.
Can anyone help on this please. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSDateFormatter dateFromString Always Returns nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300032/nsdateformatter-datefromstring-always-returns-nil)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change date format to `dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss`

Here are nice references to understand date format string: [Quick Guide to Objective-C DateFormatting](https://coderwall.com/p/jj6k_a/quick-guide-to-objective-c-dateformatting) & [Date_Field_Symbol_Table](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table)

```
y = year
Q = quarter
M = month
w = week of year
W = week of month
d = day of the month
D = day of year
E = day of week
a = period (AM or PM)
h = hour (1-12)
H = hour (0-23)
m = minute
s = second
```

If you match this with your date components

```
27-Mar-2018 18:28:09 = dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss
```

Where

```
27   = dd (date day)
Mar  = MMM (Month)
2018 = yyyy (year)
18   = HH (HH - 24 hours format and hh - 12 hours format)
28   = mm (minutes)
09   = ss (seconds)
```

Comment: To support his answer - MMM is for the month name in short form.

Comment: @Nitish - Thank you, I 'm just going to add ful description about each components with more details

Comment: Yeah.. that works for me.. Thanks for sharing those. I am so clear now.

Answer (score -1):

As your date string is "27-Mar-2018 18:28:09". The format should be "dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss".

Change the format from `"dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"` to `"dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"`